# How can I ignore the tracking of files in git

Tags: git

Git-newbie here. How can I ignore the tracking of files in git, especially for folder. I tried to use git rm but it was manual works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-can-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitign)

Comment: In general `git rm FILENAME` is the right way to make it stop tracking a file.  "it was manual works" is not a good description of the problem you are having.  I suggest you try asking again but this time copy and paste a shell session into your question that shows what you tried and what problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file named *.gitignore* inside your project directory and add  the folders/files that not intended to be tracked.

For files, only include the filename, such as foo.py

For folders, use "/" as prefix and suffix, such as /foo/

One item per line

Comment: More info about the syntax and the gitignore meachanism can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore